# Photo booth in iOS. Using OpenCV or OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es

I want to make an application filtering videos like Apple's photo booth app

How can I make that??

Using OpenCV, OpenGL ES or anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV and OpenGL have very different purposes:

**[OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opencv) is a cross-platform computer vision library**. It allows you to easily work with image and video files and presents several tools and methods to handle them and execute filters and several other image processing techniques and some more cool stuff in images.

**[OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) is a cross-platform API to produce 2D/3D computer graphics.** It is used to draw complex three-dimensional scenes from simple primitives.

If you want to perform cool effects on images OpenCV is the way to go since it provides  tools/effects that can be easily used together to achieve the desired effect you are looking for. And this approach doesn't stop you from processing the image with OpenCV and then render the result in a OpenGL window (if you have to). Remember, they have different purposes and every now and then somebody uses them together.

**The point is** that the effects you want to perform in the image should be done with OpenCV or any other **image processing library**.

Answer (score 2):

Actually karlphillip, all though what you have said is correct, OpenGL can also be used to perform hardware accelerated image processing.

Apple even has an OpenGL sample project called [GLImageProcessing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009053) that has hw accelerated brightness, contrast, saturation, hue and sharpness.